# Is it possible to paste an image from the clipboard into a question or an answer?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined

When asking a question involving system message boxes I try to insert an image of the message box in the body of the question, instead of just quoting a long message ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/343049/why-vmware-player-does-not-recognize-usb-devices)).

However, the process is tedious. I have to capture the window (Alt-PrtScr), open Paint, paste and trim the image, save a file and then upload to SE.

Is there any way of directly pasting an image from the clipboard?

Comment: This is not currently possible with the editor.

Comment: [Gee, if only SU had suggestions for making this process so much easier](http://superuser.com/questions/216772/is-there-any-tool-that-automatically-puts-screenshots-to-my-dropbox)

Comment: In Windows, can you drag files to the upload form? Because if you use the snipping tool, you basically get a file anyway, and you can press `Ctrl-G`, drag it there, and you're done.

Comment: @slhck - Thanks. I don't see the big difference between using Paint and Snipping Tool. Anyway I need to save it as a file and then upload to SE. Actually I noticed that Snipping Tool adds wide margins around the captured area, which I may need to trim anyway.

Comment: Also, I see why it is currently impossible with the editor. I tagged this as a feature-request as well. Hopefully this can be added in future revisions of the site(s).

Comment: You'll be thankful when the image hoster returns an error message and you don't have to take the screenshot again, just click *upload* again.

Comment: Note that Atlassian has this figured out - ctrl-V works in their editor.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see us supporting this anytime soon.

However, you should certainly look into applications / tools that make the initial screenshot -> file process as painless as possible, as Ivo pointed out in the comments. It could be two steps:

1. Press the magic "screenshot to file" button.
2. Upload the file via the editor web interface.

Which really isn't too bad, is it?